# Making text stand out when is overlayed over a div background image

Tags: html, css

I have two background images that I wish to use, however when I overlay them with text from a div they get drowned out by the image below.

Is there any way I can highlight my text better, whilst still preserving the sharpness and detail of the image?

There is also the option of moving the text overlay over a bit to part of the image which is a bit cleaner.

Comment: Code example please...

Answer (score 0):

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the exact problem, as I can't tell if your saying you can't see the text too well with the background image you have, or if your saying that the background image covers up the text.

If its the first one, then just try changing the 'p's color, or maybe give it a highlight with 'background-color' in your CSS.

If your saying that the image blocks out the text all together, then its probably a problem with the layering and to fix that just change the 'z-index'.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of the images involved or the text color it's hard to be sure what will fit your situation.

A couple of options spring to mind:

**1. Text Shadow**

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 320px;
  width: 240px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px white;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <h2>Title Text</h2>

</div>
```

**2. RGBA Background-color**

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 320px;
  width: 240px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
h2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <h2>Title Text</h2>

</div>
```